# Откуда пошло выражение "через пень колоду"?

Tags: фразеология

-

Answer (score 1):

*Через пень-колоду (валить) прост. неодобр. - 1. Делать что-л. кое-как, недобросовестно, нерадиво. 2. Без разбора, беспорядочно. 3. Несогласованно, с перебоями. Есть две версии происхождения этого выражения:

 1. Выражение возникло в среде лесорубов. Первоначально фразеологизм употреблялся в форме сравнения - [делать что-л.] как через пень колоду валить; валить, как через пень колоду, т. е. так же неудобно, как тащить через пень толстое бревно.

 2. Связано с хождением по буреломам, где идешь "через пень в колоду", т. е., перешагнув через очередной пень, можешь попасть ногой в трухлявую колоду.*

gramota.ru